# In a nested for loop, how can we return to the first loop from second loop?

Tags: objective-c, c, for-loop

I have 2 loops like the code below:

```
for(NSString *link in pageLinks){

    for(NSString *pattern in disallowedPattern){

        if (range.location != NSNotFound )
           // if condition is yes go back to the first loop.
    }

}
```

I want the program to return to the first loop if the condition is yes. I used `continue`, but it just returns to the second loop.  What is the solution to this?

Comment: Are you asking about C or objective C? These are two difference languages.

Comment: @ugoren Not really, ObjC is a superset of C, so everything that is allowed in C, is allowed in ObjC, too.

Comment: @JustSid, OK, they're not really different, but the distinction is still important. Is an answer that only works in ObjC OK, or is he looking for a pure C answer? There was an answer that suggested `continue label`, which isn't valid C (but it was deleted, so maybe it isn't valid ObjC either).

Comment: @ugoren It wasn't valid syntax, I guess he meant `goto` but got confused? Anyway, there is no ObjC only way to get out of an loop, so there is no distinction to make.

Answer (score 7):

`break` is what you want. It will terminate the current loop and, in your case, get back to the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `break`. The `continue` keyword just restart the current loop. (In `for` loops, `continue` will do the increment before restarting.)

Answer (score 2):

A `break;` in the inner loop resumes the outer loop immediately after the inner loop.

```
for (NSString *link in pageLinks)
{
    for (NSString *pattern in disallowedPattern)
    {
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
            break;
    }
    ...execution continues here after break is executed...
}
```

---

There's a question lurking in the comment:

> That is exactly the other problem that I've got; [I want to skip the] 'something' after the second for loop as well; is there any solution to this again?

I hope I've interpreted it correctly.  There are two possibilities, at least.  Which you choose depends in part on your attitude to `goto` statements.

#### Either (with `goto`)

```
    for (NSString *link in pageLinks)
    {
        for (NSString *pattern in disallowedPattern)
        {
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
                goto end_of_outer_loop;
        }
        ...other code to be executed if the loop terminates...
end_of_outer_loop: ;    // Null statement after the colon
    }
```

#### Or (without `goto`)

```
    for (NSString *link in pageLinks)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (NSString *pattern in disallowedPattern)
        {
            if (range.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                found = true; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            ...other code to be executed if the loop terminates...
        }
    }
```

Both work; both are reasonably clear.  It is mostly a matter of taste which you choose.

Comment: that is exactly the other problem that i got something after the second FOR-LOOP as well, any solution to this again?

Comment: What about: "if (found) continue;" which would resume the outer loop without executing "...other code to be executed if the loop terminates..." ?

Comment: @sam: yes, you could use `if (found) continue; …code…` in place of `if (!found) { …code… }`.  They're equivalent.